# web2py firebird db fails connect

Tags: python, firebird, web2py

I trying to connect a web2py app to a firebird database in another server.

This is the output message:

> Ticket ID
>   127.0.0.1.2016-01-11.12-27-33.cdefb9f6-3cc5-46ce-85dc-a2a12220e7f6
>
> Failure to connect, tried 5 times:
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py",
>   line 435, in **init** self._adapter = ADAPTERSself._dbname
>   File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py",
>   line 53, in **call** obj = super(AdapterMeta, cls).**call**(*args,
>   **kwargs) File "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/firebird.py",
>   line 121, in **init** if do_connect: self.reconnect() File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/connection.py",
>   line 105, in reconnect self.connection = f() File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/firebird.py",
>   line 119, in connector return self.driver.connect(**driver_args) File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/contrib/pypyodbc.py",
>   line 2434, in **init** self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi,
>   timeout, unicode_results, readonly) File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/contrib/pypyodbc.py",
>   line 2483, in connect check_success(self, ret) File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/contrib/pypyodbc.py",
>   line 988, in check_success ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h,
>   ret, ODBC_obj.ansi) File
>   "/home/filhofilha/Documents/Deployment/Web2Py/web2py/gluon/contrib/pypyodbc.py",
>   line 964, in ctrl_err raise Error(state,err_text) Error: (u'IM012',
>   u'[IM012] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error')

My Code:

```
dbExternal = DAL('firebird://user:password@localhost/C:\\DB.FDB', migrate_enabled=False)
```

how can I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show some the code and the connection string you use. Also is there a reason you are using ODBC, and not a Firebird driver for Python (eg fdb, firebirdsql)?

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the python firebird driver. I installed it to correct my problem